# Prevent rerendering Final Form Field

Tags: react-final-form

I've noticed a performance drop in one large form in my react app using FinalForm. Is there a Final Form way of preventing Field rerenders, more specifically rerendering a Field only when some other specific fields changes.

Imagine I have a form containing 100 fields, among which are ,  and . I want to tell fullName field only to rerender if either firstName or lastName fields changes and to NOT rerender if any of the other 97 fields changes. How to achieve this?

FormSpy, if I'm correct, only allows me to define subscription as e.g.

```
subscription={{ touched: true, error: true, value: true }}
```

whereas I'd need something like

```
subscription={{ 'values.firstName': true, 'values.lastName': true }}
```